# Change color of iPhone Slider control

Tags: iphone

[Click to see iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxbZE.png) Is there a way to change the color of a UISliderControl from blue to something else?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is stated in the UISlider class reference that you can specify images for the states - [UISlider Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006798-CH3-SW26)

> Assigning different images to each state lets you customize the appearance of the slider when it is enabled, disabled, highlighted, and so on.